# How to get the URL in javascript loaded by a jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a jsp that when returns loads a javascript that is used as a form action onclick of a button. This Javascript makes a request.open() call and the URL it needs to pass must be to a peer of the JSP that loaded it but the URL must be the one that was called. For example: 
a.jsp loads a javascript:

> function doSomething() {   var path = "some url" + "/b.jsp?"
>   + "params";   var request = new XMLHttpRequest();   request.open ("POST", path, true);   ...

If I have a HTML where I test the a.jsp by making a direct call to "http://localhost/context/a.jsp" or an environment that redirects calls to an internal server not accessible from a web browser, I want the javascript to use prefix before it calls b.jsp to be the URL that called a.jsp.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried taking out the "some url" and just passing b.jsp?  It should look at it as a relative path and go to the same directory your first jsp is in.

Comment: Currently which is limiting I am using a JSP String for The "some url":

String contextPath = request.getScheme() + "://" + request.getServerName() + ":" + request.getServerPort() + request.getContextPath();

And in the javascript the "The some url" becomes <% out.print(contextPath); %>

This is limiting as this String prints internal URLs not what is accessible from the browser.

Comment: Is the JSP page you're making the second call to in the same folder as the page you're calling it from?

Comment: in a.jsp I have form that should call b.jsp in the same app. But this action is taken from a Javascript in response to onclick() of a button